# Mobile Load Time - Compressing JavaScript

Tags: seo, mobile, page-speed, compression

Our mobile site's homepage has a load time of 10.72 seconds, which ruins our mobile SEO and therefore traffic. The site is operating on WordPress.

6.8 second of the 10.72 is spent scripting .js files.

How do I:

1) compress .js files?

2) Load and display the above-the-fold content first?

Is this at all related to caching?

Comment: Setup Cloudflare, its free and don't look back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question I would differ you to the Better Minify Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/

It will easily let you compress your .js files.

And it will allow you to move your .js scripts to the footer to enhance your above-the-fold loading. HOWEVER I want to point out that moving all of your .js scripts to the footer isn't as simple as it sounds because certain theme elements will require certain scripts to load in-order to display properly. I recommend you do this piece by piece, finding out what works and doesn't.

I would also recommend considering Cloudflare - it's a great and free way to speed up your website AFTER you complete these optimizations.

And a properly setup cache system will definitely help you with your load times also.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/

And here is full detailed instruction given here 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-minify-css-javascript-files-in-wordpress/

2. Along with it I suggest gzip your website. 
   A complete guide to it is given here : https://www.bmthrive.com/how-to-gzip-website/
3. If your website uses images then use plugin  WP SMUSHIT  to optimize images to decrease load time.
4. When using plugins then there comes query string in css  and JavaScript files like style.css?ver=5.1 which slows down website. so for it use https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/
   plugin .
5. Use Caching plugin like w3 cache.
6. Add image and css expiration tag 
   Guide : https://www.bmthrive.com/add-image-css-expiration-tag-htaccess-file/

Following all the above steps will reduce your website load time to a greatly less.

Use https://tools.pingdom.com/ to check load time before and after.

Comment: Do you have a relationship with bmthrive.com?

Comment: no ......Why so?

Comment: Just asking. When new users link to a site we don't know we like to make sure they aren't trying to promote their website on ours.

Comment: There is no harm in that as long as the content provided by the links is relevant and useful

Comment: [Not always true actually](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348489/consensus-on-self-promotion-and-spam?cb=1)